# Huge remote source to jquery autocomplete without using database

Tags: django, web-applications, jquery-autocomplete

I am working on a web app, in Django, which lets user tell their favourite movies. For the input I want to provide users a textbox with autocomplete enabled.

- The list of all movies ever made is very big (18 MB) thus autocomplete has to be enabled using remote source.
- To add to this, I have the constraint that I can not use a database. (Because my app is hosted on heroku and to store such data in database would cost a lot)

Right now, I have the list of all movies stored in a .py file, and I import it into my views.py. The view which handles the ajax request from autocomplete iterates over each movie in this list to filter based on the query term and returns the filtered list.

-movies.py

```
all_movies = [list of all movies' titles]  # > 1M string elements
```

-views.py (handle_autocomplete() gets called whenever user changes the input in the textbox on web app)

```
import movies
def handle_autocomplete(request):
     data = request.GET['term']
     my_list = [title for title in movies.all_movies if data in title]
     return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(my_list))
```

What are the disadvantages of this approach and how can I improve upon it? 
Are there any libraries/ django apps which handle remote-source autocomplete ?

Comment: Your db constraint is tough. Filtering through 18Mb of text in js will be slow, not to mension the download time...

Comment: @miki725 its not being downloaded and filtered in js...filtering is being done at server by sending requests through ajax ...using the remote source option of jquery autocomplete

Comment: ah. sorry misunderstood your question